# pip install does not copies files in site-package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have checked out https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml project from GitHub and tried to install it from local workspace in python environment after modifying the source files. But it does not save the source files in site-package dir after running "pip install -e ." command. As it does if it is directly installed from PyPi using "pip install python3-saml"
what is wrong here ? I want to put some debug in source files after git clone and install it from my local repo. Here is the successful installation log.

```
(cvenv) /home/ravi/python3-saml>pip install -v -e . 
Using pip 21.3.1 from /home/ravi/cvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
Obtaining file:///home/ravi/python3-saml
  Running command python setup.py egg_info
  running egg_info
  creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2w5sdxqh/python3_saml.egg-info
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2w5sdxqh/python3_saml.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2w5sdxqh/python3_saml.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: isodate>=0.5.0 in /home/ravi/cvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python3-saml==1.12.0) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=3.3.5 in /home/ravi/cvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python3-saml==1.12.0) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: xmlsec>=1.0.5 in /home/ravi/cvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python3-saml==1.12.0) (1.3.12)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/ravi/cvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from isodate>=0.5.0->python3-saml==1.12.0) (1.16.0)
Installing collected packages: python3-saml
  Attempting uninstall: python3-saml
    Found existing installation: python3-saml 1.12.0
    Uninstalling python3-saml-1.12.0:
      Removing file or directory /home/ravi/cvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python3-saml.egg-link
      Removing pth entries from /home/ravi/cvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/easy-install.pth:
      Removing entry: /home/ravi/python3-saml/src
      Successfully uninstalled python3-saml-1.12.0
  Running setup.py develop for python3-saml
    Running command /home/ravi/cvenv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/ravi/python3-saml/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/ravi/python3-saml/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
    running develop
    running egg_info
    /home/ravi/cvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:156: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    /home/ravi/cvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
    writing manifest file 'src/python3_saml.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
Successfully installed python3-saml-1.12.0
```

and below is setup.py file

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Copyright (c) 2010-2021 OneLogin, Inc.
# MIT License

from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name='python3-saml',
    version='1.12.0',
    description='Onelogin Python Toolkit. Add SAML support to your Python software using this library',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Intended Audience :: System Administrators',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9',
    ],
    author='OneLogin',
    author_email='support@onelogin.com',
    license='MIT',
    url='https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml',
    packages=['onelogin', 'onelogin/saml2'],
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={
        'onelogin/saml2/schemas': ['*.xsd'],
    },
    package_dir={
        '': 'src',
    },
    test_suite='tests',
    install_requires=[
        'isodate>=0.5.0',
        'lxml>=3.3.5',
        'xmlsec>=1.0.5'
    ],
    dependency_links=['http://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/tarball/master'],
    extras_require={
        'test': (
            'coverage>=4.5.2',
            'freezegun>=0.3.11, <=1.1.0',
            'pylint==1.9.4',
            'flake8>=3.6.0',
            'coveralls>=1.11.1',
            'pytest>=4.6',
        ),
    },
    keywords='saml saml2 xmlsec django flask pyramid python3',
)
```

do I need to make any changes in setup.py to make it working?